# Scripted check for a specific feature from an msi installer

Tags: powershell, automation, msi

I need to be able to check for the installation of a particular feature from an msi installer. For context, I need to check whether the "Powershell Cmdlets" feature (TFPS from Feature table in Orca) was installed from the Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools installer (tfpt.msi).

I know how to check for installation of the product itself using WMI win32_product and the product code {B6DC31D8-A303-4D14-9C88-59F183F55BEC}, but the TFPS feature doesn't even install by default so it's quite common for it to be missing.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Using the MsiQueryFeatureState should do it. You can do so from C++ or other languages. In VBScript it would be something like this (note that this is for a different MSI, please update the product GUID and feature name to suit your purpose):

```
dim installer, state

' Connect to Windows Installer object
set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
state = installer.featurestate ("{4F41AD68-89F2-4262-A32C-2F70B01FCE9E}","PhotoStory")

If ( state = -2 ) then
  MsgBox "INSTALLSTATE_INVALIDARG"
 elseif (state = -1) then
  MsgBox "INSTALLSTATE_UNKNOWN"
 elseif (state = 2) then
  MsgBox "INSTALLSTATE_ABSENT"
 elseif (state = 2) then
  MsgBox "INSTALLSTATE_ADVERTISED"
 elseif (state = 3) then
  MsgBox "INSTALLSTATE_LOCAL"
 elseif (state = 4) then
  MsgBox "INSTALLSTATE_SOURCE"
End If
```

The interesting state is INSTALLSTATE_LOCAL. This means the feature is installed locally on the local disk.

Here is more information on the down to the wire C-style win32 call: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370361(v=vs.85).aspx